# How to upcast an static std::optional

Tags: c++, c++17, upcasting, stdoptional

```
class Child: public Base {.....}

class Child
{
    static std::optional<Base>& Child::GetBaseInstance()
    {
        static std::optional<Base> instance = std::make_optional<Chid>; \\Does not work. Please help
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to return an instance but of type of std::optional of it's base. Also should I be returning std::optional& or std::optional<Base&> if I'm trying to pass the same reference?

Comment: consider that `std::optional` is specifically for cases where you want to avoid dynamic allocation of the contained object. If thats not an issue a smart pointer can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `std::optional` for references. Instead, either use a raw pointer, a `std::reference_wrapper`, or `boost::optional` (which works for references).

That being said, you have another flaw in your snippet: `std::optional<Base>` suffers from object slicing when constructed from a `Child` instance. You can read more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Note that you can also use the `nullptr`-like state of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to indicate the additional boolean property of your object. When dealing with class hierarchies, it often makes sense to use these smart pointers, while `std::optional` is rather a good fit for value-type objects.